# Поочерёдно выполнять по одной итерации цикла в разных потоках

Tags: c#, многопоточность, семафоры

Никак не соображу, как это реализовать.

Имеется рабочий поток, вызываемый N раз одновременно и поток-диспетчер. В обоих содержатся некие циклы.

Цикл потока-диспетчера:

> 1. Выполняет 1 итерацию.
> 2. Даёт разрешение рабочим потокам.
> 3. Ждет, когда каждый из них выполнит 1 итерацию.

Цикл рабочего потока:

> 1. Ждёт разрешения от диспетчера.
> 2. Выполняет 1 итерацию.
> 3. Сообщает о завершении итерации.

Сказали, что можно реализовать с помощью семафора, но я никак не соображу, как. Я только понял, как с его помощью можно ограничить доступ к фрагменту кода, но как быть с описанном выше случае?

Необходимо обязательно использовать потоки.

PS: если кого-то смутит отсутствие описания выхода из циклов - они конечные, просто, здесь это не важно.

Upd: похоже, меня не совсем поняли. Методы потоков выглядят так:

```
//поток-диспетчер
static void ProtocolThread(object input) {
  //...
  do {
    //...
    //здесь он должен давать разрешение и ждать
  } while (!complited);
  return;
}

//рабочий поток (вызывается несколько таких параллельно)
static void ThreadMethod(object input) {
  //...
  do {
    //здесь он должен ждать разрешение
    //...
    //здесь сообщить о завершении итерации (если это необходимо)
  } while (!complited);
  return;
}
```

Потоки запускаются так:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ProtocolThread));
```

Comment: Вы обращаетесь к разделяемой переменной `completed` без синхронизации? Ну-ну.

Comment: Нет нет, там на самом деле разные выражения. Это я для краткости написал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дополнительный ответ для случая, когда рабочие потоки не являются одинаковыми - и требуется дополнительная защита от выполнения одним потоком сразу двух задач.

1. У WaitHandle есть такой метод, как SignalAndWait. Этот метод работает атомарно. Если применять его в рабочих потоках над двумя семафорами - это позволит гарантировать, что к моменту пробуждения диспетчера все рабочие потоки уже уснут.
2. Также у семафоров есть метод, позволяющий сделать операцию Release сразу N раз, тоже атомарно. Применение этого метода в тот момент, когда все рабочие потоки спят, разбудит их всех одновременно.

При помощи этих двух трюков, доступных благодаря богатству WinAPI, можно решить задачу без ввода дополнительных примитивов.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не должны использовать такие низкоуровневые конструкции, как семафоры и потоки. В C# есть более удобные конструкции.

Если вам нужно выполнить лишь по одному заданию, делайте так:

```
void Iteration() { ... }

// main
Iteration();
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(Iteration));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Если действительно нужны потоки, то

```
Iteration();
var threads = new List<Thread>();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    var t = new Threads(Iteration);
    t.Start();
    threads.Add(t);
}

foreach (var t in threads)
    t.Join();
```

---

Если рабочий поток один, можно воспользоваться producer-consumer'ом:

```
BlockingCollection<int> q = new BlockingCollection<int>();

// main

var t = new Thread(Consumer);
t.Start();

Iteration();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    q.Add(i);

q.CompleteAdding(); // останавливаем

t.Join();

// ----------------------------------

void Consumer()
{
    foreach (var n in q.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        Iteration();
}
```

Comment: В данном случае задача требует именно применение потоков, так что такой вариант не подходит.

Comment: Почему? Учебное задание?

Comment: Да, учебное. При этом ничего толком не объяснено. Не совсем понял ваш способ. Что означает `Iteration();`? Добавил к вопросу общий вид методов потоков. Пожалуйста, покажите на их примере.

Comment: @InfernumDeus: Ну, у вас в условии сказано «выполняет 1 итерацию». Вот это и есть та самая итерация.

Answer (score 1):

Заведите **два** семафора. Одним семафором задача не решается.

Первый семафор будет использоваться для выдачи разрешения на работу. Второй - для сигнализации о окончании обработки.

А дальше делайте так, как написано в задании. Там и так все уже по шагам расписано.

Comment: Точно. Спасибо. Пока обедал пол часа назад, осознал точно то же самое.

Comment: Хотя опять не до конца понял. Как это организовать с учетом того, что количество рабочих потоков произвольное (N)? Скажем, в конце потока-диспетчера я полностью освобожу семафор на N единиц. Как только это произойдёт, ожидающие в данный момент рабочие потоки запустят цикл. Но что, если один такой поток успеет завершить итерацию до того, как какой-то другой даже не успеет подойти к циклу? Не получится ли, что один поток после одного разрешения выполнит 2 итерации, а другой 0?

Comment: Потоки одинаковые? Делают одно и то же? Тогда в чем проблема? :)

Comment: Ну, они одинаковые, но должны параллельно обрабатывать последовательность из разных однотипных данных. Задание предполагает строгую последовательность действий: поток-диспетчер вывел содержимое глобальной переменной (массива) -> каждый рабочий поток выполнил ровно одну итерацию -> диспетчер вывел... и так далее.